# Wordpress show future events based on custom field

Tags: wordpress, date, custom-post-type

I know similar questions are asked a million times and i have tried different kinds of solutions but without any success

I have Cpt contests

```
<?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ?get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $contest = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                        'post_type' => 'contests',
                        'posts_per_page' => '15',
                        'meta_key'=> '_closingdate',
                        'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
                        'order' => 'ASC',   
                        'paged' => $paged
)); 
?>

<?php if ($contest->have_posts()) :  while ($contest->have_posts()) : $contest->the_post();?>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="cell_left"><p><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p></div>
                    <div class="cell"><p class="posted"><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_closingdate",true)));?></p></div>                                           
                  </div>
                   <?php endwhile;?> 


            </div>



            <div class="navigation">      
            <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $contest ) ); ?>          
          <?php wp_reset_query();?> 

    </div>
                   <?php endif; ?>
```

This is working without any problem

now i try to only show "contests" with closing date today and future. 
i have found this on stack overflow but i cant get it working .

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ?get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$today = date('Ymd');
$contest = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'contests',
        'posts_per_page' => '15',
        'meta_key' => '_closingdate',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_closingdate',
                        'meta-value' => $value,
                        'value' => $today,
                        'compare' => '>=',
                        'type' => 'CHAR',
                         )
                            )
));
?>
```

Is there someone who can solve this quest for me ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try using php [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function:

in your case

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ?get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$contest = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'contests',
        'posts_per_page' => '15',
        'meta_key' => '_closingdate',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_closingdate',
                        'value' => time(),
                        'compare' => '>=',
                         )
                            )
));
?>
```

Comment: Hi Mark , i have tried your suggestion but no succes , is it possible that the problem is in the combination of my Query and my Loop ?  because the date is stored in my database as yyyy-mm-dd and i return it in my loop as dd-mm-yyyy . ?

Comment: @Jeroen - Ohh I didnt know you were storing in that format...Personally I use jQuery datepicker and the alternate field I use unix timestamp